# Are the SO moderators overworked?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Reading the blurbs of the candidates for the moderator election, and reading through the town hall meeting last night, a common theme that came up was that SO moderators have a *lot* of stuff to do.  The candidates were asked if they had enough time, and if they understood the workload that would become their responsibility.

Just wondering how true that is, and how often SO's number of moderators increases (and based on what criteria).

Comment: Related: [Should Stack Overflow moderators have a “standard of duty”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101431/should-stack-overflow-moderators-have-a-standard-of-duty). There are no "moderator ranks": it's an elected position.

Comment: @MarkTrapp -- sorry, bad phrasing, I meant ranks as in the number of moderators ... will edit.

Comment: I did ask if the [current mods think SO needs more mods](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/505?m=1880534#1880534), so the answers to that might help

Comment: To be fair, "do you have enough time" and "do you understand the workload" are questions that come up in nearly every SE election.

Comment: @AnnaLear you can blame Mrozek for that. It's like his tradition to ask those :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SO has moderator elections when they feel like they need more moderators. Typically about once a year. Currently there are 10 SO moderators and this election will swell their ranks to 14.

SO gets a lot of flags (>1k/day if I'm hearing correctly) and that is one of the primary duties of moderators.

However, the SE development staff has been putting a lot of time recently into reducing the work load for these moderators. For example they have made some changes to the flag queue for 10k rep users so that they can share more of the burden. For instance very low quality and off topic flags hit the 10k flag queue first.

SO moderation is still a huge job, it involves both moderation on SO and on MSO. Its easily the biggest site on the network and the proportion of mods to questions is also smaller than it is anywhere else. Thankfully SO has a lot of very active high rep users who share some of the moderation duties. But that doesn't mean its not a big job.

An SO mod would have to actually answer the "are they overworked question" but I think that this is probably relative to an individual moderator. Remember this is voluntary position and if they feel overworked they can resign. However I think SE is trying very hard right now to mitigate those feelings and help ease the work load on the individual moderators both through better tools and now more mods.

Comment: @yoda updated to reflect those comments.

Comment: And not all of those 10 moderators are actually actively moderating to the same degree.